# Unable to get scaleLinear() to populate values into SVG Rectangle's width

Tags: d3.js

Please look at this `index.html` with simple `d3.js` scaling:

```
    <body>
    <script>
        var canvasWidth = 750;
        var canvasHeight = 600;

        // Setup scales
        d3.json("tt.json", 
                function(data)
                {
                    var widthScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                                        .domain([0, 3])
                                        .range(0, canvasWidth);

                    var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                                        .domain([0, 10])
                                        .range(["red", "blue"]);

                    var canvas = d3.select("body")
                                    .append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", canvasWidth)
                                    .attr("height", canvasHeight)

                    canvas.selectAll("rect")
                            .data(data)
                            .enter()
                                .append("rect")
                                .attr("width", function(d) { return widthScale(d.t_count); })
                                .attr("height", 30)
                                .attr("y", function(d, i) { return i * 50; })
                                .attr("fill", "blue")

                    canvas.selectAll("text")
                            .data(data)
                            .enter()
                            .append("text")
                            .attr("fill", "black")
                            .attr("y", function(d, i) { return (i * 50 + 22); })
                            .text(function(d) { return d.ttext; })
                }) // of function(data)             
    </script>
</body>
```

The `.json` file on the server looks like this:

```
[{"ttext":"Architect","t_count":"1"},
{"ttext":"Entertainment","t_count":"2"},
{"ttext":"Food","t_count":"2"},
{"ttext":"Gujarati","t_count":"1"},
{"ttext":"Laundry","t_count":"1"},
{"ttext":"Milk","t_count":"2"},
{"ttext":"Rajasthani","t_count":"1"}]
```

The output is just this:

[image]

(nothing but the `ttext` attribute from the `json` file.)

A hardcoded factor i.e., `return (d.t_count * 30);` **does** plot the rectangle. But when the scaling is introduced, the text is all that is output.

Here's the SVG DOM that is generated (strangely missing `width` in the `rect`):

[image]

Struggling with this for a day almost. Can anyone review and please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a scale, both `domain` and `range` have to be arrays.

So, change to this:

```
var widthScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 3])
    .range([0, canvasWidth]);//range as an array
```